# Apache proxy auth against digest backend

Tags: apache2, mod-proxy, digest-authentication

I'm migrating a backend Basic Auth to Digest Auth.

Until now, we have an first tier apache2 server making the authentication via header overwrite to avoid users knowing the backend credentials:

```
 <Location />
            ProxyPassReverse "http://192.168.110.111/"
            ProxyPass       "http://192.168.110.111/"
            RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic dXNlcjp1c2Vy"
 </Location>
```

However, Digest authentication requires some extra work to manage nonce variable fields and such stuff.

Does anybody know if there is any way to make the Digest login to the backend automatically from the Apache server against the proxyed backend?

Thanks!!

Comment: I have this same issue. Did you manage to find a solution?